# Get Commit object by hexsha in git-python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to find the content of the commits that have been checked in between two specific commits.

In git I'd do `git rev-list --ancestry-path <older_commit_sha>..<newer_commit_sha>`.

In git-python, since it doesn't look there's a direct way of doing it, I resorted to calling the exact command, through `repo.git.execute()`.
The output is a string of commit IDs (hex SHA).

Now, is there a way in git-python to create a valid `Commit` object starting from the hex SHA as given by `execute()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking, and given this question is not getting much traction, I resorted to using `.execute()`.
Specifically:

```
commits = repo.git.execute(['git', 'rev-list', '--ancestry-path',
                            '%s..%s' % (oldCommit.hexsha, newCommit.hexsha)]).split()
```

Of course, `oldCommit` and `newCommit` are `git.Commit` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a function in git-python to get the spcific commit object by sha.
So I can only think of itering all the commits to get it:

```py
def get_commit_by_sha(repo, sha):
    for c in r.iter_commits():
        if c.hexsha == last_one:
            return c
    return None
```

As for comparing the difference between two submissions specific commits.
`diff` method is useful, a simple usage:

```py
old_commit.diff(new_comit.hexsha)
```

The result is a `git.diff.DiffIndex` object, refer to https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.diff.DiffIndex

Comment: You can use Repo.commit method to get specific commit object by sha. Just pass sha string as `rev` argument. For example: `repo.commit('8556c92f96022162da21684194febfa617ead5e1')`

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad bit late (like, almost 6 years late), but I somehow figured out how I can do this.

```
commits = list(repo.iter_commits("{}..{}".format(begin_sha, end_sha), "", ancestry_path=True))
```

This will return the Commit object list within (`begin_sha`, `end_sha`] (with `--ancestry-path` enabled). I suspected that the `kwargs` at the end of the argument list of `iter_commits` are supposed to be redirected to `git rev-list`, so I just gave it a shot whether I can specify toggle options too other than value options like `--after`. Seems like it works.

I blame the lack of a proper reference manual for having to figure this out with trial and error. :(